# No access via cygwin to USB connected device (Samsung Galaxy tab II)

Tags: hard-drive, usb, cygwin

In Cygwin, I am used to being able to have access to a USB-connected device via a drive letter. For example, my Droid X2 appeared as E://, so I could do:

```
 $ cd E:/<something>/
```

and get access to everything in there.

However, my Samsung tablet appears as a drive called GT-P3113, with no associated letter.  And, looking in /dev, I see nothing.  I have access to the drive in Windows, of course, but not in Cygwin.  I have the same problem with my Galaxy Note II phone.

How can I have access to this drive via Cygwin command line?

```
 Windows 7  
 CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 $USER 1.7.10(0.259/5/3) 2012-02-05 12:36 i686 Cygwin
```

Comment: The difference here is that your Droid X2 is mounted as a mass storage device, and your tablet and other phone are mounted as MTP devices. MTP devices arn't actually mounted as drives and there's some advantages (you can still work on the device while its mounted) and disadvantages here.

Comment: Ah.  So no hope of using cygwin to access an MTP device as if it were a file system?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. A common workaround seems to be to set up a smb client and use that instead

Comment: Okay, will look into that.  Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I checked that, and turning debugging, no luck :/

Comment: If you're simply trying to transfer files via cygwin, [**`adb`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) would work.  If you choose to use wireless ADB, do so with extreme care, as IIRC, it's not secure or encrypted _(a USB connection for ADB with host verification is always preferred to Wireless ADB)_

Answer (score 1):

Well on my Samsung Player, Open 'Settings' under that 'wireless and network' there is a 'USB settings', under that is 'Select as a Media player or Mass storage' Select Mass storage and you should be able to see your tablet as a drive. Hope this helps Ciff